# I get 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' in type cast. Question: How to Create generic response model

Tags: json, flutter, list

In some cases, the response.data can come as an object or a List
example

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "userID": "YSXrcA",
            "emailAddress": "john@mailinator.com",
            "fullName": "John",
            "phoneNumber": "12345676556",
            "profilePic": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ddvype20r/image/upload/7/Group_720_wdae1i.png",
            "referralCode": "Ffit7q",
            "registerDate": "2023-12-06T20:25:37+01:00",
            "userType": "renter"
        }
    ]
}
```

**OR**

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "data": 
        {
            "userID": "YSXrcA",
            "emailAddress": "john@mailinator.com",
            "fullName": "John",
            "phoneNumber": "12345676556",
            "profilePic": "https://res.cloudinary.com/ddvype20r/image/upload/7/Group_720_wdae1i.png",
            "referralCode": "Ffit7q",
            "registerDate": "2023-12-06T20:25:37+01:00",
            "userType": "renter"
        }
    
}
```

I have a response model that looks like this model class

```
class ApiResponseModel {
  final int status_code;
  final String? status;
  final String? message;
  final Map<String, dynamic>? data;
 

  ApiResponseModel({
    required this.status_code,
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, ) =>
      ApiResponseModel(
        status_code: json["status_code"],
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
     data: json['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>?,
      );


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status_code": status_code,
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": data!,
      };
}
```

then i can make a call

```
 Future<ApiResponseModel> login({required Map payload}) async {
    try {
      final result = await apiService.postRequest(
        endpoint: '/user/auth/login',
        data: payload,
      );

      return ApiResponseModel.fromJson(result);
    } catch (err) {
      logger.log("Login Error: $err");
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

this works fine if the response is the second from the responses above, but when it a list  i get the error
error rrr: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' in type cast

Comment: You need to pattern match on whether data is a simple object or an array of objects.  This is fortunately not a very common design, but you have to change gears to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I create an extra Model For case 1,

```
class ApiResponseModel {
  final int status_code;
  final String? status;
  final String? message;
  final List<ApiResponseDataModel> data;
  ApiResponseModel({
    required this.status_code,
    this.status,
    this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  ApiResponseModel copyWith({
    int? status_code,
    String? status,
    String? message,
    List<ApiResponseDataModel>? data,
  }) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      status_code: status_code ?? this.status_code,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      message: message ?? this.message,
      data: data ?? this.data,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'status_code': status_code,
      'status': status,
      'message': message,
      'data': data.map((x) => x.toMap()).toList(),
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      status_code: map['status_code'] as int,
      status: map['status'] != null ? map['status'].toString() : null,
      message: map['message'] != null ? map['message'].toString() : null,
      data: List<ApiResponseDataModel>.from(
        (map['data'] as List).map<ApiResponseDataModel>(
          (x) => ApiResponseDataModel.fromMap(
              x as Map<String, dynamic>), // look what i did here
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromJson(dynamic source) =>
      ApiResponseModel.fromMap(source as Map<String, dynamic>);
}

class ApiResponseDataModel {
  final String userID;
  final String emailAddress;
  final String fullName;
  final String profilePic;
  final String referralCode;
  final String registerDate;
  final String userType;
  ApiResponseDataModel({
    required this.userID,
    required this.emailAddress,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.profilePic,
    required this.referralCode,
    required this.registerDate,
    required this.userType,
  });

  ApiResponseDataModel copyWith({
    String? userID,
    String? emailAddress,
    String? fullName,
    String? profilePic,
    String? referralCode,
    String? registerDate,
    String? userType,
  }) {
    return ApiResponseDataModel(
      userID: userID ?? this.userID,
      emailAddress: emailAddress ?? this.emailAddress,
      fullName: fullName ?? this.fullName,
      profilePic: profilePic ?? this.profilePic,
      referralCode: referralCode ?? this.referralCode,
      registerDate: registerDate ?? this.registerDate,
      userType: userType ?? this.userType,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'userID': userID,
      'emailAddress': emailAddress,
      'fullName': fullName,
      'profilePic': profilePic,
      'referralCode': referralCode,
      'registerDate': registerDate,
      'userType': userType,
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponseDataModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ApiResponseDataModel(
      userID: map['userID'].toString(),
      emailAddress: map['emailAddress'].toString(),
      fullName: map['fullName'].toString(),
      profilePic: map['profilePic'].toString(),
      referralCode: map['referralCode'].toString(),
      registerDate: map['registerDate'].toString(),
      userType: map['userType'].toString(),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ApiResponseDataModel.fromJson(dynamic source) =>
      ApiResponseDataModel.fromMap(
          source as Map<String, dynamic>); // look here, i used dynamic
}

Future<List<ApiResponseModel>> login({required Map payload}) async {
  try {
    final List<ApiResponseModel> fetchList = [];
    final response = await apiService.postRequest(
      endpoint: '/user/auth/login',
      data: payload,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      for (var e in result) {
        fetchList.add(ApiResponseModel.fromJson(e));
      }
    } else {}
    return fetchList;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.log("Login Error: $err");
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

For case 2,

```
class ApiResponseModel {
  final int status_code;
  final String? status;
  final String? message;
  final ApiResponseDataModel data;
  ApiResponseModel({
    required this.status_code,
    this.status,
    this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  ApiResponseModel copyWith({
    int? status_code,
    String? status,
    String? message,
    ApiResponseDataModel? data,
  }) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      status_code: status_code ?? this.status_code,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      message: message ?? this.message,
      data: data ?? this.data,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'status_code': status_code,
      'status': status,
      'message': message,
      'data': data.toMap(),
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ApiResponseModel(
      status_code: map['status_code'] as int,
      status: map['status'] != null ? map['status'].toString() : null,
      message: map['message'] != null ? map['message'].toString() : null,
      data: ApiResponseDataModel.fromMap(map['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ApiResponseModel.fromJson(dynamic source) =>
      ApiResponseModel.fromMap(source as Map<String, dynamic>);
}

class ApiResponseDataModel {
  final String userID;
  final String emailAddress;
  final String fullName;
  final String profilePic;
  final String referralCode;
  final String registerDate;
  final String userType;
  ApiResponseDataModel({
    required this.userID,
    required this.emailAddress,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.profilePic,
    required this.referralCode,
    required this.registerDate,
    required this.userType,
  });

  ApiResponseDataModel copyWith({
    String? userID,
    String? emailAddress,
    String? fullName,
    String? profilePic,
    String? referralCode,
    String? registerDate,
    String? userType,
  }) {
    return ApiResponseDataModel(
      userID: userID ?? this.userID,
      emailAddress: emailAddress ?? this.emailAddress,
      fullName: fullName ?? this.fullName,
      profilePic: profilePic ?? this.profilePic,
      referralCode: referralCode ?? this.referralCode,
      registerDate: registerDate ?? this.registerDate,
      userType: userType ?? this.userType,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'userID': userID,
      'emailAddress': emailAddress,
      'fullName': fullName,
      'profilePic': profilePic,
      'referralCode': referralCode,
      'registerDate': registerDate,
      'userType': userType,
    };
  }

  factory ApiResponseDataModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ApiResponseDataModel(
      userID: map['userID'].toString(),
      emailAddress: map['emailAddress'].toString(),
      fullName: map['fullName'].toString(),
      profilePic: map['profilePic'].toString(),
      referralCode: map['referralCode'].toString(),
      registerDate: map['registerDate'].toString(),
      userType: map['userType'].toString(),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ApiResponseDataModel.fromJson(dynamic source) =>
      ApiResponseDataModel.fromMap(
          source as Map<String, dynamic>); // look here, i used dynamic
}

Future<ApiResponseModel?> login({required Map payload}) async {
  try {
    ApiResponseModel? fetchList;
    final response = await apiService.postRequest(
      endpoint: '/user/auth/login',
      data: payload,
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body);
      final item = ApiResponseModel.fromJson(result);
      fetchList = item;
    } else {}
    return fetchList;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.log("Login Error: $err");
    rethrow;
  }
}
```